# Research papers that demonstrate work done on other species with honey bee pheromones

Tags: sociality

I found [research where](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28150219) Queen mandibular pheromones (QMP) emitted by queen bees were used to find their affects on *Drosophila melanogaster*. However, I am curious to see if the QMP from bees have been used in other social insects like wasps or termites. Can you please guide me to any research papers on the same?

Since the eusocial queen pheromones among different species are more or less composed of the same hydrocarbons, treating wasp workers with honey bee QMP should have the same effect on worker wasps as it would have had on honey bee workers.